# How to get a list of existing topics in an Azure EventGrid Domain in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-eventgrid

What is the best way to retrieve a list of topic names that are encapsulated by an Azure EventGrid Domain in C#?

It is easy enough to do this with Azure-CLI, but struggling to find examples of this in C#. I've looked at [EventGridManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/eventgrid/management?view=azure-dotnet) with usage sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events/blob/master/EGManageTopicsAndEventSubscriptions/EGManageTopicsAndEventSubscriptions/Program.cs), however, I feel there is too much overhead to try and get this to work, mainly to do with credentials and authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API call [Domain Topics - List By Domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/domaintopics/listbydomain) to get the list all the topics in a domain.
Once your application has an Authorization Bearer access token, you can get any resource.

Have a look at my article [Azure Event Grid Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester) based on the Azure API Management using a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) calls.

The following screen snippet shows getting a list of all the topics in a domain by Azure Event Grid Tester:

[image]